# How to access web application with another subnet?

Tags: networking, routing

My computer ip is 10.0.0.19 and my default gateway is 10.0.0.2 I need to access web application with ip 192.168.0.120 using default gateway 10.0.0.190. I'm not sure how to do that ?

Comment: You'll have to add a route in your router between the two networks. Is there a reason you're using two subnets on your Lan?

Comment: How are your computer, gateway 10.0.0.2 and web server 192.168.0.120 connected to each other? Why do you talk about gateway 10.0.0.2 and gateway 10.0.0.190? Is one the gateway to the internet and the other one the gateway to the internal 192.168.0.x network? Can you please add information about your operating system (probably as a tag)!?

Comment: Without knowing the details of your network, such as what router(s) you have and how everything is connected, it's impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can start a `cmd.exe` as an administrator and there run

```
route add 192.168.0.120 mask 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.190
```

to create a route only for this IP or

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.190
```

to create a route for the complete 192.168.0.x network.

Using Linux the commands would be (don't forget to replace eth0 with the right interface)

```
ip route add 192.168.0.120 via 10.0.0.190 dev eth0
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.190 dev eth0
```